# How to access express route inside basicAuth

Tags: node.js, express

My NodeJS server, using express, has a bunch of entries to specify various routes:

```
app.post('list_streams.json',    auth, stream_handler.list_streams);
app.post('add_stream.json',      auth, stream_handler.add_stream);
app.post('delete_stream.json',   auth, stream_handler.delete_stream);
etc...
```

The auth middleware is written like this:

```
var auth = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback) {     
    user_handler.authenticate_user(user, pass, callback);
});
```

Inside the user_handler.authenticate_user() function, an access to the database is performed to validate the user. I'd like to add some statistics and keep track of every access that a particular user performs. I'd like to do this inside the authenticate_user() function, as this is where a database is accessed for the user record and I can use the same access to update the statistics info in the user record, but I need to somehow pass an extra argument to the authenticate_user() specifying the type of access that was performed; either the route itself or some token that identifies the route being accessed. And I can't figure out how to do this. The 'req' is not available inside the authenticate_user() function.

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: Please note that express.basicAuth was deprecated in express@4.*.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need can be easily done from your authenticate_user function since it's only called once per session at the first access from any user.

The best approach to log ALL access per user would be to create a new middleware function as described at the end of this post.

But assuming you only wish to log user authentications, one way to solve your problem would be to replace express.basicAuth with your own version that binds the callback function to the express `req` object, like this:

```
var util=require('util'),
    express=require('express'),
    app=express(),
    auth=basicAuth(function(username,password,next){
        console.log('auth has access to req as "this": %s',util.inspect(this));
    });

app.get('/',auth,function(req,res){
    console.log('in request for "/", req is: %s',util.inspect(req));
    res.send('SUCCESS');
});

app.listen(4000,function(){
    console.log('running');
});

// Replacement for connect.basicAuth (as used by express)
// lifted from https://github.com/expressjs/basic-auth-connect

function unauthorized(res, realm) { // required by basicAuth
  res.statusCode = 401;
  res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="' + realm + '"');
  res.end('Unauthorized');
}

function error(code, msg){ // required by basicAuth
  var err = new Error(msg || http.STATUS_CODES[code]);
  err.status = code;
  return err;
}

// replacement basic auth which binds the callback to the "req" object
function basicAuth(callback, realm) {
  var username, password;

  // user / pass strings
  if ('string' == typeof callback) {
    username = callback;
    password = realm;
    if ('string' != typeof password) throw new Error('password argument required');
    realm = arguments[2];
    callback = function(user, pass){
      return user == username && pass == password;
    }
  }

  realm = realm || 'Authorization Required';

  return function(req, res, next) {
    var authorization = req.headers.authorization;

    // 20140601 RR - !!NOTE!! bind callback to req
    callback=callback.bind(req);

    if (req.user) return next();
    if (!authorization) return unauthorized(res, realm);

    var parts = authorization.split(' ');

    if (parts.length !== 2) return next(error(400));

    var scheme = parts[0]
      , credentials = new Buffer(parts[1], 'base64').toString()
      , index = credentials.indexOf(':');

    if ('Basic' != scheme || index < 0) return next(error(400));

    var user = credentials.slice(0, index)
      , pass = credentials.slice(index + 1);

    // async
    if (callback.length >= 3) {
      callback(user, pass, function(err, user){
        if (err || !user)  return unauthorized(res, realm);
        req.user = req.remoteUser = user;
        next();
      });
    // sync
    } else {
      if (callback(user, pass)) {
        req.user = req.remoteUser = user;
        next();
      } else {
        unauthorized(res, realm);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the line marked with "!!NOTE!!" above, you'll see that the callback you pass to the new basicAuth function has been bound to express' `req` request object, which makes its idea of `this` a reference to the request.

Now all you need to do is reference `this.url` to get the original request URL and log it.

As mentioned above, one thing to note is that the callback to `auth` is only called to authenticate the user once.

Subsequent requests already have the req.user HTTP header variable set, so the request is allowed to pass without calling the authentication callback.

This is why the best way to log all interactions for a particular user would be to add your own middleware after the call to `auth`, such as:

```
function logUser(req,res,next){

   // since this middleware is called AFTER auth, the user is already authorized.
   log.info('user "'+req.user+'" called url:'+req.url);

   next(); // pass control to the next stage in fulfilling the request
}

app.get('/',auth,logUser,function(req,res){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Rob, thank you for your detailed explanation. I am actually using  basicAuth in someone unorthodox way, with every request received by the server, I am sending an authentication token that was obtained at login time, and I am using basicAuth to call my token authentication logic. So, basicAuth is called every time, and as part of the token authentication, the data base is accessed and I wanted to leverage that access to update the stats. I've decided against that approach and went ahead with the 2nd solution that you proposed. Thank you again.